# Moving mail from Gmail 'Important' folder in Outlook to Inbox

Tags: vba, outlook, gmail

I have set up Outlook to retrieve all of my gmail. Most of the emails are going to the 'Important' folder, hidden in the [Gmail] folder.

I'm trying to automatically move all mail from Important to Inbox.

I get an error on `Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("Important")`.

```vb
Sub MoveItems()
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myInbox As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myDestFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim myItem As Object
    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myInbox = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myItems = myInbox.Items
    Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("Important")
    Set myItems = myInbox.Folders("Inbox").Items
    'Debug.Print myItems.Count
    For i = myItems.Count To 1 Step -1 'Iterates from the end backwards
        myItems.Item(i).Move myDestFolder
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It depend on where the Important folder is created in Outlook. If that folder is a subfolder of the Inbox folder then you can use the following code:

```
Set myDestFolder = myInbox.Folders("Important")
```

But if the folder is created the same level (a sibling to the Inbox) you need to get the parent folder of the Inbox folder and then try to retrieve the folder:

```
Set parent = myInbox.Parent
Set myDestFolder = parent.Folders("Important")
```

A hidden folder will have the `PR_ATTR_HIDDEN` set. You can use [MFCMAPI](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/mfcmapi) or OutlookSpy for exploring internal structure of folders in Outlook. Note, you can also iterate over all folders in Outlook recursively to make sure the Important folder is there.

Answer (score 0):

Given this folder structure:

```
me@gmail.com
-Inbox
-[Gmail]
--Important
```

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub MoveItems()
    
    Dim myGMailInbox As Folder
    Dim myGMailGmailFolder As Folder
    
    Dim mySourceFolder As Folder
    Dim myDestFolder As Folder
    
    Dim mySourceItems As Items
    
    Set myGMailInbox = Session.Folders("me@gmail.com").Folders("Inbox")
    Set myDestFolder = myGMailInbox
    
    Set myGMailGmailFolder = Session.Folders("me@gmail.com").Folders("[Gmail]")
    Set mySourceFolder = myGMailGmailFolder.Folders("Important")
    Set mySourceItems = mySourceFolder.Items
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = mySourceItems.count To 1 Step -1  'Iterates from the end backwards
        Debug.Print mySourceItems.Item(i).subject
        mySourceItems(i).Move myDestFolder
    Next
    
End Sub
```